# Sbt autoplugin to override project settings

Tags: scala, plugins, sbt

I am trying to develop a very small autoplugin to override the local configuration of all projects and subprojects. Specifically, I'd like my plugin to change the scalaVersion and add one option to the scalacOptions of the project that includes it. [I have read in the documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Setting-Initialization.html) that one can alter the order in which settings are assigned, but it seems that I am not assigning them to the correct project.
This is the code I have so far:

```
// build.sbt 
import AddSettings._ 

lazy val root = (project in file(".")) 
  .settingSets(userSettings, defaultSbtFiles, autoPlugins, buildScalaFiles)
  .settings( 
     sbtPlugin := true, 
     name := "sbt-scalafix-config",
     organization := "io.prl-prg", 
     version := "0.0.1", 
     addSbtPlugin("org.some" % "some-other-plugin" % "0.5.3")
   ) 

// PluginCode.scala 

package config 
import sbt._ 
import sbt.Keys._ 

object PluginCode extends AutoPlugin {
  override def trigger = allRequirements 
  override lazy val projectSettings = Seq(
    scalaVersion := "2.12.3", 
    scalacOptions := Seq( "-Yrangepos" )
  )
  println("[PluginCode Setup] Hello World!")
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't want to use `addSettings`, as

1. It will probably destroy the behavior of all the *other* `AutoPlugin`s in your build, and,
2. It's gone in sbt 1.x anyway (for the reason above, I wager)

`AutoPlugin`s are not supposed to overwrite settings in projects. Projects should always have the final say about their own settings, so that makes sense.

You can easily do the `scalacOptions` part by using `+=` instead of `:=` (in the plugin *and* in the projects). In general, you should virtually never use `:=` with Seq-settings, and `scalacOptions` in particular.

```
override def projectSettings = Seq(
    scalacOptions += "-Yrangepos"
)
```

For `scalaVersion`, well, if the project explicitly sets `scalaVersion`, there's nothing your `AutoPlugin` can do to overrule it. And it shouldn't be able to. However, you could get the effect you want if the project does not define `scalaVersion` at the project-level (but maybe at the `in ThisBuild` level, for example).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's nice to know that it can't be done, I can stop face-tabling now. However, is there any way to achieve the same effect without editing a project's `.sbt` files directly?